# XSL text output - trim blank lines and leading spaces

Tags: xslt

I have an XSLT that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" indent="no" encoding="utf-8" media-type="text/plain" />
    <xsl:template match="/SOME/NODE">
        <xsl:if test="./BLAH[foo]">
<xsl:value-of select="concat(@id, ',' , ./BLAH/bar/@id, ',' , ./blorb/text())"/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output looks something like this (it is going to be a CSV file):

```
    1,2,3
    4,456,22

    90,5,some text


    365,16,soasdkjasdjkasdf
    9,43,more text
```

What I need is for it to be transformed into:

```
1,2,3
4,456,22
90,5,some text
365,16,soasdkjasdjkasdf
9,43,more text
```

The main problems are the blank lines (from nodes that do not match the IF condition) and the indentation. Is there any way to remove the blank lines and trim the indentation while preserving the line breaks after lines that are not blank?

I've tried using `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>`, but then the output looks like this:

```
1,2,3,4,456,22,90,5,some text,365,16,soasdkjasdjkasdf,9,43,more text
```

Which doesn't work since I need to have 3 values on each line.

As requested, a (heavily simplified) sample of the input:

```
<SOME>
    <NODE>
        <BLAH id="1">
            <foo>The Foo</foo>
            <bar id="2" />
            <blorb> some text </blorb>
        </BLAH>
    </NODE>
    <NODE>
        <BLAH id="3">
            <bar id="4" />
            <blorb>some text that shouldn't be in output because there's no foo here</blorb>
        </BLAH>
    </NODE>
    <NODE>
        <BLAH id="5">
            <foo>another Foo</foo>
            <bar id="6" />
            <blorb>some other text</blorb>
        </BLAH>
    </NODE>
</SOME>
```

Comment: Please show us the input. I am guessing you want to use `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>`, but we really need to reproduce the problem before suggesting solutions.

Comment: @michael.hor257k: I've tried using `strip-space`. I've updated the question to reflect this.

Comment: Why don't you show us an example of the input as requested? -- P.S. If you want a return, you need to output it explicitly - just like any other character.

Comment: @michael.hor257k: Simplified version of input is posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you approach it this way:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text"  encoding="utf-8" />

<xsl:template match="/SOME">
    <xsl:for-each select="NODE/BLAH[foo]">
        <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="bar/@id"/>
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="blorb"/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: With `strip-space`, this works perfectly! Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner There is no reason why this shouldn't work perfectly even without `xsl:strip-space`.

Comment: @michael.hor275k: You're probably right, but... it's not! For what it's worth, I'm using the XSLT processor that's built in to Eclipse, "JRE Instance Default", though when I tried switching to the Xalan processor, it gave the same results (blank lines and indentation) if `strip-space` wasn't there.

Comment: You can see it working here: http://xsltransform.net/bnnZXe But if your input is different ...